# How do I set an unlimited size to the history file for tcsh?

Tags: command-history, tcsh

This is a follow-up question to [Is there a maximum size to the bash history file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17574/is-there-a-maximum-size-to-the-history-file).

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the atmospheric science department computers, as they use tcsh rather than bash.

Also, for some reason, the history file keeps on getting replaced whenever I quit my remote putty session and start a new one. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a good starting point:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070715091413640

```
set history = 2000          # History remembered is 2000
set savehist = (2000 merge) # Save and merge with existing saved 
set histfile = ~/.tcsh_history
 ...in .tcshrc and this line... 
history -S
 ...in .logout solved the problem.
```

> Now history is not only preserved between Terminal sessions, but also
>   merged (considering command dates).

Another note, just because the login shell is tcsh doesn't mean you have to use it.  Do you have bash installed?  Can you run:

```
$ bash
```

If that works, you can just put a 'bash --login' in your .tcshrc and then use bash (or zsh if you are feeling advantageous).

Comment: If you just want to use bash as suggested, you'll also want `setenv SHELL /bin/bash` in your .tcshrc, per http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/how-to-change-from-csh-to-bash-as-default-shell/20635#20635